# Strange issue in Eclipse about Chinese character

Tags: eclipse

platform：`opensuse leap 42.2 KDE`
Eclipse：Version: `Oxygen Release (4.7.0)  UTF-8`

```
xxx@linux-bq5s:~> java -showversion
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

I use Java write a simple code, the code is fine since I can run it in a special way (shows in the image), so don't focus too much on the code.

[image]

I put in the word "高数" ，but as you can see, it returned something else, but it's not done yet, look at the second picture.

[image]

I copied the word "高数" in input filed at somewhere else that I typed in, and I paste in the Eclipse input filed and enter, it returned correct.

I have changed another Input Method, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Nithin: please do not add "any help appreciated" and other chatty material. That stuff is _removed_ here, not added.

Answer (score 0):

I run the code in terminal, and input normally, and it seems alright, so I think the problem is in the Eclipse

```
xzyx@linux-bq5s:~/桌面> java User
请输入指令：1-按书名选择；2-按序号选择    
1
请输入书名
高数
您已选择：高数
xzyx@linux-bq5s:~/桌面> java User 
请输入指令：1-按书名选择；2-按序号选择
1
请输入书名
电子
您已选择：电子
```

In Eclipse, when I add a table before input the charater "高数", the code could work correct, I think there is something wrong with Eclipse's input field.